# PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied after using distutils

Tags: python, pandas, csv, distutils, python-re

I keep running into this error in Python and I'm none the wiser. I have copied a few folders and files from one directory to another:

`copy.py`

```
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree

fromDirectory = "C:/X"
toDirectory = "C:/Y"

copy_tree(fromDirectory, toDirectory)
```

`convert.py`

```
import re 
import pandas as pd 

csv_data = pd.read_csv("C:/Y/data/file.csv")
print(csv_data)
```

And now everytime I run `python convert.py` I get:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:/Y/data\\.git\\objects\\pack\\pack-0cf6f7607e31cd733126c67e6a432945fc6a6a71.idx'


 raise DistutilsFileError(
distutils.errors.DistutilsFileError: could not delete 'C:/Y/data\.git\objects\pack\pack-0cf6f7607e31cd733126c67e6a432945fc6a6a71.idx': Access is denied
```

I've tried running VSCode in administrator, and also `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`. It doesn't seem to work, what's happened here?

Comment: I have ran your code and it is working except add '.csv' to path.

Comment: Sorry @Hassan, I've just added the csv file- missed it the first time. It still doesn't work for me.

Comment: Can you update the error message?

Comment: Figured out the issue. There was another repo within my repo causing all sorts of problems. Now solved! @Hassan

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the issue. There was another .git file in the folder that I copied, and this resulted in there being two repositories inside my project. That's why there was a .idx file in there causing issues. It's solved now after I deleted this.